# Convertin the typeof string to number

Tags: javascript

The easiest way to convert the type of this string to a number?

```
var x = prompt("enter your number:");
```

without x = +x .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add plus before prompt :

like this :

```js
const x = +prompt("enter your number:");
```